# How to calculate exact distance between two locations using latitude,longitude of two coordinates

Tags: php, haversine

I am using google api

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" . $prev_lat . "," . $prev_long . "&destination=" . $currentlat . "," . $currentlong . "&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true"
```

to calculate distance between two points. But I am not getting exact distance.
Please help me out from this problem

Comment: How about using `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2)` function? You need to load geometry and places api when load the maps api

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "distance"? The distance as the crow flies, or how far you have to walk/drive/fly/swim to get from point A to point B?

Comment: have you considered using the haversine formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula ?